How to show value of item missing in SelectOneMenu primefaces jsf
Is there a way to show the value of set Item that is not in the
<p:selectOneMenu id="myItem" value="#{bean.myEnumId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.myEntityItems}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

Is there a setting in the selectOneMenu of primefaces to still show the value of bean.myEnumId if the id is not in the items of the bean.myEntityItems?
For example we have a scenario that we can set a businessCode, but this business codes available can be change in the future like be disabled as non selectable.
I was thinking of using itemDisabled but it presents other issues like it does not work. All item are still enabled.
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.myEnumIds}" var="item"
                                    itemLabel="(#{item.value}) #{item.label}"
                                    itemValue="#{item.value}" itemDisabled="true" />

